# Dropdown options are not getting selected (select 2) using SELENIUM and JAVA

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, drop-down-menu

I've been trying without success to select an option from a dropdown select 2 class.

```
<span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-OperativeUnit_Id-container" title="Newsan">Newsan</span>
```

I did this then in Selenium and the dropdown is selected:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"select2-OperativeUnit_Id-container\"]")).click();
```

The problem is that i can select no option at all. The dropdown has this:

```
<ul class="select2-results__options" role="tree" id="select2-OperativeUnit_Id-results" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false">
<li class="select2-results__option select2-results__option--highlighted" id="select2-OperativeUnit_Id-result-1jq8-81" role="treeitem" aria-selected="true">Company1</li>
<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-OperativeUnit_Id-result-fjep-281" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Company2</li>
<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-OperativeUnit_Id-result-e8a1-408" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Company3</li>
</ul>
```

What should i do to select the option "Company2"?

Comment: Can you post the URL?

Comment: Hey pal. it's not public at all, it's hidden

Comment: @AbiSaran i don't understand how to select an option from a select2 dropdown, tried a lot of different things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"select2-OperativeUnit_Id-container\"]")).click();
```

Try

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(.,'Company2')]")).click();
```

You can make the locator more precise with this:

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='select2-results__option' and contains(.,'Company2')]")).click();
```

Comment: Hey pal, i'm checking it out. It seems to be selecting it but the option selected vanish

Comment: You didn't (can't) share the link and all your code so I'm not sure we can ques why the option get disappearing

Comment: No, it is not getting selected it is like "refreshing" the page

Comment: The XPATH from option Company 2 is: //*[@id="select2-OperativeUnit_Id-result-spkb-408"]

Comment: Xpath can be determined by any combination of attributes. Based on what you shared xpath I gave you is unique while id attribute seems to contain some dynamic suffix.

Comment: I don't understand because by using your code it seems to be doing "something" but after executing your code it is like the page itself refresh

Comment: I re-tried this: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='select2-results__option' and contains(.,'Company2')]")).click(); and now it worked. Could you please explain to me why sometimes driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(.,'Company2')]")).click(); works but in this case this one was the indicated: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='select2-results__option' and contains(.,'Company2')]")).click();

Comment: What's behind that? Why sometimes work and sometimes doesnt?

Comment: The first locator not precise enough, it can match some other element. I don't know. Need to debug but I can't ...

Comment: The second locator contains class attribute making the locator more unique and stable

Comment: Pal, take a look at this: <input id="AccountNumber_1" type="text" data-index="1" data-name="AccountNumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Account Number">
I did this but it seems not to be inserting the data. Am i missing some other value to specifiy:
driver.findElement(By.id("AccountNumber_1")).sendKeys("001712");

Comment: It worked by doing this: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"AccountNumber_1\"]")).sendKeys("001712");

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"select2-OperativeUnit_Id-container\"]/li[2]").click()
```

#OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'Company2')]")).click()
```

Comment: Hey, thnks for replying!. No, it is not working. It is not getting selected.

Comment: No, i don't know why but it is not working at all. The XPATH from option Company 2 is: //*[@id="select2-OperativeUnit_Id-result-spkb-408"]

Comment: Hey pal, i solved this by using this: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='select2-results__option' and contains(.,'Company2')]")).click(); from Prophet. Why his method worked but different methods dont? why?